# Keep running jar file background Centos

Tags: centos, vnc

I use jar file that listen to socket and other users connect to this file

When i run jar file in putty tools and leave it (close it) and clients can connect to it

But after a day,clients cannot connect to it and i have to run it again

I try login into Centos with VncViewer and open terminal and run jar file

Is it possible if i use VncViewer?

Comment: What is your issue you want to start using vnc viewer or you want that it never comes down once you start it?

Comment: @Katiyman I want to keep running jar file in background for always only